# How to get the next number infront of a searched string in a string in c programming

Tags: c

This is my String "**This is just a text. Data: Is invalid. Restful information. Actual Position:1234 System requirements**".

My searched string is "**Actual Position:**" and I am interested in having the number infront which changes all the time the motor is moved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you try? Please post a [mcve]. Also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)  (see [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for format) for this. You can do something along the lines of this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  int i=-1;
  char sentence[]="This is just a text. Data: Is invalid. Restful information. Actual Position:1234 System requirements";
  char key[]="Actual Position:";
  char* subst= strstr(sentence, key);

  if(subst != 0){
     int n = sscanf (subst,"Actual Position:%i",&i);
     if (n  > 0){
         printf ("Found Actual Position => %d\n",i);
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that @SteveMclaren , as I said  it was untested, and I was a bit rustier on sscanf than I thought. Should work now though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `strstr` to search, then use the position pointer with the length of `"Actual Position:"` and finally use the `sscanf` to read the value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{
    char data[] = "This is just a text. Data: Is invalid. Restful information. Actual Position:1234 System requirements";
    char srcData[] = "Actual Position:";
    char *pos = strstr(data, srcData) + strlen(srcData);
    int value = 0;
    sscanf(pos, "%d",&value);
    printf("%d",value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C.

Comment: Ok, updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot I will try implementing this in my code.

Comment: Is there an altenative to sscanf? its like its not working in wxwidgets.

Comment: sscanf worked on char*, it should work. Describe the problem you are facing

Comment: void Main::OnReadTimer( wxTimerEvent& event ){

  char message [1000] = {0};
  SerialReadLine(message, 1500);
  char search[] = "Aktuelle Position:";
  char *ptr = strstr(message, search) + strlen(search);
  int pos = 0;
  sscanf(ptr, "%d",&pos);
  wxString tok;
  tok << pos;
  get_position->SetValue(tok);}       This is the method under wxwidgets. My program crashes when launched.

Comment: SerialReadLine(message, 1500);printf("%s",message); and then paste the result that are printed in console. And your message variable should contain "Aktuelle Position:", then it will work.

Comment: The result is a string that contains the Actual Position i've been looking for. I wish to grab the index of that position and send it to a textfield.

Comment: But in code you used: "Aktuelle Position:" as search string.